# "Fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is overdetermined" without any BC's

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions, notation

Consider this system of PDEs.

```
eqn1 = D[u[x, t], x] + 5 D[u[x, t], x, x] + D[v[t], t, t] - 4 == 0
eqn2 = D[v[t], t] + D[u[x, t], t, t] + v[t] == 0
```

I would like to solve this system under the boundary conditions.

```
BCE1 = DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 1, x == 0]
BCE2 = DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 2, x == 2]
BCTot = {BCE1, BCE2}
IC1 = u[x, 0] == 0
IC2 = v[0] == 1
icTot = {IC1, IC2}
solution = NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, BCTot, icTot}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[First[u[x, t] /. %]], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1},PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Attempting to do so gives me the error

```
NDSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables, {u[x,t]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined.
```

Ok, so my system is overdetermined, something is obviously wrong with my boundary conditions. However, completely removing all reference to boundary conditions (including restarting Mathematica) still gives the exact same error.

```
solution = NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Do you need `u[x,t]` and `v[x,t]` in the final `NDSolve`?

Comment: Changing u and v to u[x,t] and v[t] in the last line doesn't remove that error message. I get an additional error message however: Function::fpct: Too many parameters in {x,t} to be filled from Function[{x,t},1][t].

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you started:

BCs and ICs need to be consistent. You need ICs and derivatives of ICs (you have second order time derivatives). Mixing `u[x,t]` and `v[t]` is most likely not going to work.

```
eqn1 = D[u[x, t], x] + 5 D[u[x, t], x, x] + D[v[x, t], t, t] - 4 == 
   0;
eqn2 = D[v[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], t, t] + v[x, t] == 0;
BCE1 = u[0, t] == 0;
BCE2 = u[2, t] == 2;
BCTot = {BCE1, BCE2};
IC1 = {u[x, 0] == x, Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0};
IC2 = {v[x, 0] == 1, Derivative[0, 1][v][x, 0] == 1};
icTot = {IC1, IC2};
solution = 
 NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, BCTot, icTot}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

This gives a message but then I did chose some values arbitrary.

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[First[u[x, t] /. %]], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I was looking to solve (eventually) a system of differential equations. In this system, differential equations of different forms couple together; this is why I have u[x,t] and v[t]. An analogy would be heat transfer through a medium (u[x,t])where one end is in contact with a gas reservoir governed by a form of the differential clausius-clapeyron equation. In this case v[t] can be written as v[x,t] but would only have coupling on the boundary i.e. only includes a term D[v[x, t], x] /. x -> 0.
Aside, is there really no way to solve u[x,t] and v[t]?

Comment: @Iamtired, not that I know of. I think there are a couple of similar examples on this site but I can not find them right now.